# Data bind in knockout is not working for multiple attributes

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-3.0

I have a following div tag with data binding

It gives following error

Bindings value: visible:showBannerMessage , style:{backgroundColor: #ffeea8;height: 40px}
Message: Invalid or unexpected token

Where am i commiting mistake?
Thanks

Comment: My div line is as follows

<div data-bind="visible:showBannerMessage , style:{backgroundColor: #ffeea8;height: 40px}" class="oj-flex-bar oj-sm-align-items-center;">

Comment: The error is as follows

Bindings value: visible:showBannerMessage , style:{backgroundColor: #ffeea8;height: 40px}
Message: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: The `;` between `#ffeea8` and `height` should be a `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you pass to the `style` binding should be a valid javascript object, not a css string. You've made two mistakes:

- `property: value` pairs should be delimited by a `,`, not a `;`
- string values should be enclosed by quote marks. Both `40px` and `#ffeea8` should be wrapped in `''`.

I.e., the correct binding is:

```
/*              comma -------------v                */
style: { backgroundColor: '#ffeea8', height: '40px'  }
/*            quotes -----^-------^----------^----^ */
```

Here's a reproduction of your faulty view, showing the error you've described, and a correct one that includes fixes to these two changes:

```js
// Wrong view
try {
  ko.applyBindings({
    showBannerMessage: true
  }, document.getElementById("wrong"));
} catch(err) {
  console.log("error:", err.message);
}

// Right view:
ko.applyBindings({
  showBannerMessage: true
}, document.getElementById("right"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- with errors -->
<div id="wrong" data-bind="visible:showBannerMessage, style:{backgroundColor: #ffeea8; height: 40px}">Hello world</div>

<!-- without errors -->
<div id="right" data-bind="visible:showBannerMessage, style:{ backgroundColor: '#ffeea8', height: '40px' }">Hello world</div>
```